# Get metadata by media_id Not owned by itself graph api facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I wan to get metadata of media instagram. but I can only get metadata of my post and can't get post not owned.
[my post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmkJ0.png)

[public post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HNxD.png)